# RecycleView in which every single item of Arraylist contains two arraylist

Tags: android, dynamic, view, android-recyclerview

In RecycleView have an Arraylist and every single item contains two arraylists of different sizes,actually i want to show cart item but my problem is every single order has two type of order one is package type and other is box type ,i want to show data as i have given order and data show according to invoice number and every single item has different number of product of both type,i have parsed data correctly but issue in giving specific layout.My layout can differentiate every particular order which has multiple data.Here my adapter class.

```
public class OrderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderAdapter.ItemRowHolder> {

ArrayList<OrderBean> listByInvoice;
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<OrderBean> orderBeanArrayList;
private int counter;

public OrderAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<OrderBean> orderBeanArrayList) {
    this.orderBeanArrayList = orderBeanArrayList;
    this.mContext = context;

    listByInvoice = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
public ItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v;

    v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_order, viewGroup, false);
    v.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(
            RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    ));
    ItemRowHolder mh = new ItemRowHolder(v, mContext);
    return mh;

}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemRowHolder itemRowHolder, final int i) {

    if (i < orderBeanArrayList.size() - 1) {
        int menulist = orderBeanArrayList.get(i).getOrderMenuBeanArrayList().size();
        int boxlist = orderBeanArrayList.get(i).getOrderBoxBeanArrayList().size();
        int customerlist = orderBeanArrayList.get(i).getOrderBoxBeanArrayList().size();

        for (int k = 0; k < menulist; k++) {


        }
        for (int m = 0; m < boxlist; m++) {

        }
    } else {
        Log.e("LAST", "");
    }


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return orderBeanArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    return super.getItemViewType(position);

}

public class ItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView tv_serviceType;
    TextView tv_PackageTitle, tv_DATE, tv_TIME, tv_TOTAL_PRICE, tv_Status, tv_orderdatetime;
    TextView tv_BoxTitle, tv_BoxDATE, tv_BoxTIME, tv_Box_TOTAL_PRICE, tv_Box_orderdatetime, tv_Box_Status;
    LinearLayout linear_box, linear_service, ll_menu, ll_box;
    CardView cardView_header;
    Button btn_viewMenu, btn_viewDetail;

    public ItemRowHolder(View view, final Context mContextv) {
        super(view);

        tv_serviceType = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_serviceType);
        tv_PackageTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_PackageTitle);
        tv_DATE = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_DATE);
        tv_TIME = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_TIME);
        tv_TOTAL_PRICE = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_TOTAL_PRICE);
        tv_Status = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_Status);
        tv_orderdatetime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_orderdatetime);

        tv_BoxTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_BoxTitle);
        tv_BoxDATE = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_BoxDATE);
        tv_BoxTIME = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_BoxTIME);
        tv_Box_TOTAL_PRICE = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_Box_TOTAL_PRICE);
        tv_Box_orderdatetime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_Box_orderdatetime);
        tv_Box_Status = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_Box_Status);

        linear_box = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linear_box);
        linear_service = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linear_service);
        ll_menu = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ll_menu);
        ll_box = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ll_box);
        cardView_header = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardView_header);

        btn_viewMenu = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_viewMenu);
        btn_viewDetail = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_viewDetail);


    }

}
```

i leaved blank loop in which i have tried so many think but it did not work for me , i have created dynamic view but it is also creating problem.
[image: My order look like this and every order has multiple items but they are different from each other.]

Comment: Have you considered using Nested RecyclerViews

Comment: Take a look at this blog http://blog.aimanbaharum.com/2016/01/25/nested-recyclerviews/

Comment: thanks for giving reply , i have already known about nested recycleview but my data is not like to set in inner recycle view.

Comment: Regardless if the item is package or box it will have products inside it so you can create recycler view for the items and each item should have a recycler view for the products

Comment: i  have to two different type of Arraylist one is Ordermenu and other is Orderbox ,if i used inner recycleview to inflate product but how i will manage two diffrent array list

Comment: U can make ordermenu and orderbox inherited from a base object and make the inner recycler view accept an arraylist of the parent type